# Refrescar modelo con eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, blade

Bueno lo que sucede es que, estoy desarrollando el modulo de configuración de perfil de usuario, en la vista recupero su información, el problema esta con la foto al actualizarla, porque al guardar la nueva imagen y volver a intentar modificar el perfil este busca la primera imagen, es decir, la foto que tenia el usuario al iniciar sesión. Esto tenia inicialmente:

```
 let aux = '{{ route('uploads', ['file' => Auth::user()->foto]) }}';
            $('#foto_previa').attr('src', aux).show('slow');
```

Probe con el metodo refresh de eloquent pero no tuve resultados diferentes:

```
let aux = '{{ route('uploads', ['file' => Auth::user()->refresh()->foto]) }}';
                $('#foto_previa').attr('src', aux).show('slow');
```

Es importante indicar que si recargo la pagina si puedo obtener dicha informacion, pero necesito que se pueda actualizar varias veces la foto sin tener que recargar la pagina. Gracias

Comment: Es que el código de PHP se ejecuta del lado servidor, por eso `Auth::user()->foto` no va a cambiar hasta que recargues la página

Comment: Vale gracias, pero si existirá alguna solución para ese problema en específico?

Comment: Seria colocar ese código pero dentro del controlador y refrescar el div ?

Comment: ¿Y por qué no recargas la página luego de actualizar la imagen?

Comment: Es que quería mostrar una notificación con toastr